C# filter objects in GUI at runtime by complex criteria ("lambda expression from textbox")
I am wondering whether there is a good approach to enable users of a C# GUI to search/filter objects in a list by complex criteria of their choice.
I imagine something like a lambda expression that the user types into a textbox and that the code then applies to the list of items it has.
E.g. if the tool shows a list of cats that each have {name, color, age, sex, hat, ...} and the user wants to find all the orange female cats with a name that wear a black cylinder-hat, then they should be able to filter it via typing into a textbox x.hat.type == "Cylinder" && x.hat.color = "black" && x.color == "orange" && x.sex == "female".
For this I have two rough ideas:

parse the user text prompt and filter myself. I can try to match the written criteria with fields of the object by using reflection. This would also enable me to implement an auto-complete or suggestion feature...
But it is quite a lot of work compared to an out-of-the-box feature and I am not sure whether I would manage to handle filters for sub-items like the cat's hat well.

Create a database object of some kind and then find out whether Microsoft offers nice ways to use this database object. The search above sounds like a chain of WHERE-commands to me, so if databases in C# can be accessed well during runtime, then I could use that option.
But I am not at all familiar with databases and even less so with database-objects in C#.


So what do you think? Do you know a simpler/better approach?
Background: As a side project I am developing a little tool to allow my coworkers and me to manage the complex project relevant items (neither cats nor hats) that we work with on a daily basis.
In my own user experience searching and filtering is a key part of any tool that shows long lists of items. The problem is that there are many different such items and some of them are intertwined, like e.g. cats wear hats and hats are worn by different cats. And some types have maaany fields. So I search for a good approach how to best filter these items. And before I (not an app developer) start using my maybe-super-dumb approach, I figured I'd first ask the experts here.
Thanks for for your time! Any comment is well appreciated! :)

A text box won't make any of you or your users happy. You'd have to parse, compile and fortify against malicious injection attacks...

Malicious intent won't be an issue, as it is an internal tool that works on local data only. I parsed other logical expressions (which was a pain to do, but well...), so I think this would be an OK approach if there is no totally different solution to this. I would love to just offer a little script-interface that allows dynamic access to fields at runtime...
